# MQ7 with Java 7 and SSL is not working., it was working before 6 months

Tags: java, ssl, mq

We have **One QM** and **One CHANNEL** and **many QUEUES** created for clients. Around 5 clients are connected to this QM for their transactions. Each 5 clients connected to their **respective QUEUES** . There is a jks  file created in this QM  for **SSL connection**. Each 5 clients connect with **jks file + SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA** from their javaClient. QM is also configured with **SSLCIPH(RC4_SHA_US)**.

Now all of a sudden , without any javaClient change , 1 client could not able to connect to configured QM. All others are able to connect to same QM , without any issue.

AMQERR01.LOG is not logged with any specific exception or error

In application logs its saying common MQ exception
Error as **com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2397'**

2397 - Cipher spec<>suite not matching--is any possibility?

we enabled tracing (strmqtrc -m TEST.QM -t detail -t all) and saw Trace logs in path (C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Websphere MQ\trace) ,but could not get any details on why SSL-connection could not happening?

We done one more exercise like created a new QM for issue client and tested without SSL and its working. When we enabled SSL in new QM and javaClient , the same  2397 started logging.

Could someone guide me for better logging and tracing in MQ , which can see why 2397 is throwing?
Could someone guide me for better logging and tracing in Java using -D [-Djavax.net.debug=all]  , which can see why 2397 is throwing?

MQ Version ->7
MQ Server in ->Windows

from trace logs

```
returning TEST.QM
Freeing cbmindex:0 pointer:24DDB540 length:2080
-----}  TreeNode.getMQQmgrExtObject (rc=OK)
cbmindex:10
-------------}  xcsFreeMemFn (rc=OK)
------------}  amqjxcoa.wmqGetAttrs (rc=OK)
-----{  UiQueueManager.testQmgrAttribute
-------------{  Message.getMessage
testing object 'TEST.QM'
An internal method detected an unexpected system return code. The method {0} returned {1}. (AMQ4580)
checking attribute 'QmgrCmdLevelGreaterThan'
-------------}  Message.getMessage (rc=OK)
for value '510'
-----------}! NativeCalls.getAttrs (rc=Unknown(C35E))
-----}  UiQueueManager.testQmgrAttribute (rc=OK)
Message = An internal method detected an unexpected system return code. The method wmq_get_attrs returned "retval.rc2 = 268460388". (AMQ4580), msgID = AMQ4580, rc = 50014, reason = 268460388, severity = 30
result = true
---}  TreeNode.testAttribute (rc=OK)
---{  TreeNode.testAttribute
-----{  QueueManagerTreeNode.toString
-----}  QueueManagerTreeNode.toString (rc=OK)
testing object 'TEST.QM'
checking attribute 'OamTreeNode'
-----------{  NativeCalls.getAttrs
------------{  amqjxcoa.wmqGetAttrs
qmgr:2A7B32C8, stanza:2A7B32C4, version:1
for value 'true'
QMgrName('TEST.QM')
-----{  TreeNode.getMQQmgrExtObject
StanzaName('QMErrorLog')


testing object 'TEST.QM'
Full QM.INI filename: SOFTWARE\IBM\MQSeries\CurrentVersion\Configuration\QueueManager\TEST!QM, Multi-Instance: FALSE
--------------}  xcsGetIniFilename (rc=OK)
--------------{  xcsGetIniAttrs
---------------{  xcsBrowseIniCallback
FileType = (1)
----------------{  xcsBrowseRegistryCallback
xcsBrowseRegistryCallback
-----------------{  xusAddStanzaLineList
------------------{  xcsGetMemFn
checking attribute 'PluginEnabled'
component:24 function:15 length:2080 options:0 cbmindex:0 *pointer:24DDB540
------------------}  xcsGetMemFn (rc=OK)
for value 'com.ibm.mq.explorer.oam'
RetCode (OK)
-----------------}  xusAddStanzaLineList (rc=OK)
-----------------{  xusAddStanzaLineList
------------------{  xcsGetMemFn
-----{  UiPlugin.isPluginEnabled
component:24 function:15 length:2080 options:0 cbmindex:1 *pointer:24DDDFE8
------------------}  xcsGetMemFn (rc=OK)
RetCode (OK)
-----------------}  xusAddStanzaLineList (rc=OK)
testing plugin_id: com.ibm.mq.explorer.oam
-----------------{  xurGetSpecificRegStanza
-------{  PluginRegistrationManager.isPluginEnabled
Couldn't open key (QMErrorLog) result 2: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

MQ version 7.0.1.9

jdk1.8.0_181-i586
com.ibm.mq*jar  Version
Specification -version : 6.0.2.1
Implementation-Version :6.0.2.1 -j600-201-070305

Comment: Did the version of Java (major or minor) change?   The error you show doesn't appear relevant to the client issue.  Please provide full 4 digit server and `com.ibm.mq*jar` versions along with the output of `java -version`.

Comment: <MQ version 7.0.1.9
><
<jdk1.8.0_181-i586
><com.ibm.mq*jar  Version<>
Specification -version : 6.0.2.1<>
Implementation-Version :6.0.2.1 -j600-201-070305>

Comment: Is the Java version the same with working and non-working?

Comment: yes.. jdk1.8.0_181-i586 is the same...working and no-working

Comment: All other versions are the same?

Comment: seems cipher issue or JDK8 won't support weak cipher... ISSUE RESOLVED WITH DOWNGRADE JDK TO  jdk1.7.0_60

Comment: How was 1.8.0_181 working with the same cipher on other hosts?   Upgraded JRE that no longer supported older SSL V3 ciphers was my original suspect.  Why are you using MQ jars from a version that hasn't been supported in almost **8** years and was released over 15 years ago?  Even your queue manager version has not been supported in almost 5 years and was released 8 years ago?

Comment: * SSL:
    * AllowSSLV3=Y
    * AllowWeakCipherSpec=Y

Comment: in unix/linux...i know where qm.ini, In windows ..we could not able to see this file..to add above entries

Comment: organization is in upgrade mode to jdk8+mq9 with TLS

Comment: If you want the v6 client jars you need to read those values it would not, those settings didn't exist in v6.0.  I'm still not sure how the same cipher work on other servers with the exact same version of Java.

Comment: we tried with some strong cipher and that too failed.. don't know why that failed... will update with ciphers we tried

Comment: V6 jars did not support anything but sslv3 and tksv1.0.

Comment: for  jdk8+mq9 with TLS , we already given readme for com.ibm.mq*jar Version9

Comment: any thoughts on why these not logged in AMQERR01.LOG or trace?

Comment: Please expand what is not logged.   Please confirm java version on working system was different and not the same as you previously claimed